# Update column if at least one is filled in grouping by

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update **col_a** to fill in the empty columns with "**App**" if at least one of the one of them is filled in with "**App**" grouping by **col_b**

I'm having a difficult time of thinking how to do this.

Current situation:
Table A

```
+----+--------------+------+
|id  | col_a        | col_b|
+----+--------------+------+
| 1  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 2  | NULL         | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 3  | NULL         | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 4  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 5  | Tus          | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 6  | NULL         | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 7  | Hoe          | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 8  | NULL         | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 9  | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 10 | NULL         | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 11 | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 12 | NULL         | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
```

Desired outcome:
Table A

```
+----+--------------+------+
|id  | col_a        | col_b|
+----+--------------+------+
| 1  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 2  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 3  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 4  | App          | 1111 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 5  | Tus          | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 6  | NULL         | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 7  | Hoe          | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 8  | NULL         | 2222 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 9  | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 10 | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 11 | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
| 12 | App          | 3333 |
+----+--------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update your_table_name
set col_a = 'App'
where col_b IN (select col_b from your_table_name where col_a = 'App')
```

Filter all the `col_b` values and update only those who have `col_b` value present in filtered values.

You can further optimize it this way using `is null`:

```
update your_table_name
set col_a = 'App'
where col_a IS NULL and col_b IN (select col_b from your_table_name where col_a = 'App')
```

**#UPDATE:**

- The above query throws an error of same table name was mentioned twice in **MySQL**.

**Method 1:**

To avoid this issue, we can create an alias of the table name and tweak it as shown below:

```
update your_table_name
set col_a = 'App'
where col_a IS NULL and col_b IN (select col_b from (select * from your_table_name) t2 where col_a = 'App')
```

**Method 2:**

We can do an inner join of the table with itself and grouping `col_b` values which have `App` in them and then update rows accordingly. This would improve performance.

```
update your_table_name t1
inner join (
    select col_b
    from your_table_name
    where col_a = 'App'
    group by col_b
    having count(col_b) > 0
) t2
on t1.col_b = t2.col_b 
set t1.col_a = 'App'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond, I've changed the query a little bit because I got an error. But it works now!

Comment: @Memphor you will need to change the table name.

Comment: @Memphor hello. When the answer was helpful to solve your problem please accept it as the best answer to let others know, that your problem is solved.

Comment: @vivek I've changed `update your_table_name set col_a = 'App' where col_a IS NULL and col_b IN (select col_b from your_table_name where col_a = 'App')` **to** `update your_table_name as t1 set col_a = 'App' where col_a IS NULL and col_b IN (select col_b from (SELECT * FROM your_table_name) as t2 where col_a = 'App')` and it works now.

Comment: @Memphor Thanks, didn't notice MySQL would throw such errors(maybe due to concurrent select and update on the same table). I have added 2 methods as per your update.